# wondering why scalaz Task.runAsyncInterruptibly not interrupting as i would expect it to

Tags: scala, concurrency, task, scalaz

I've been looking at this presentation https://github.com/indyscala/scalaz-task-intro/blob/master/presentation.md and was confused about one of the code snippets it presented using Task.runAsyncInterruptibly (slightly modified appears below):

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import scalaz.{-\/, \/-}

object Junk extends App {

  val neverMind = new AtomicBoolean(false)
  System.out.println(s"neverMind set to $neverMind on thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")

  val t = Task {
    System.out.println(s" in task run block on thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
    Thread.sleep(4000)
    System.out.println(s" completed sleep of 40000 ms on thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
  }

  Task.fork(t).
  //t.
    runAsyncInterruptibly({
    case -\/(t) => t.printStackTrace()
    case \/-(()) => println(s"Completed (right) branch of case on thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
  }, neverMind)


  println("sleeping 1000, then set nevermind to true")
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  neverMind.set(true)
  println("woke up. set cancel=true -- expect stack trace not 'Completed' message")

  Thread.sleep(4000)

}
```

I am puzzled because I set the 'cancel' flag (neverMind.set(true)), but I don't see  a stack trace. the code block within delay {...} eventually prints 'completed successfully'.     This is so simple, I am sure I am making a dumb mistake.. not sure where though !

I have sought advice from some colleagues who pointed out that my original example did not use Task.fork() so i was doing everything on the same thread... doh!  OK. i corrected that. and it still does not work.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer has to do with the trampolining inside scalaz's Task/Future, as it only checks `cancel` in between steps (see `listenInterruptibly` inside scalaz's `Future`.

If you change the Task to:

```
val t = Task.delay(System.out.println(s" in task run block on thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName}"))
.map(_ => Thread.sleep(4000))
.map(_ => System.out.println(s" completed sleep of 40000 ms on thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName}"))
```

you'll see it gets canceled before the "completed sleep" step. It still didn't seem to call the handler that prints the stack trace, though.